# Same enum not working in different columns in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, enums

All these enums are not added in diff columns.

**My model:**

```
enum relationship_status: [:Married, :Single, :Engaged, :Divorced, :Widowed, :Separated, :Complicated,:All]
enum gender: [:Male, :Female,:All]
enum qualification: [:Uneducated,:Matric, :Inter, :Graduation, :Masters, :PHD,:All]
```

It returns the following error:

```
You tried to define an enum named "gender" on the model "Campaign", but this will generate a instance method "All?", which is already defined by another enum
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: your enum `gender has :All` and `qualification has :All`

Answer (score 6):

> How I fix it?

Don't include `:all` in your `enum`'s, set a different value OR use a prefix/suffix:

```
enum gender: [:male, :female, :both]
```

If you look at their [docs](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html), you'll see that you can have a [suffix or prefix](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html):

```
enum gender: [:male, :female, :both], _prefix: :gender
```

This will give you:

```
@object.gender_male?
@object.gender_female?
@object.gender_both?
```

---

The reason why you're getting the error is because the `enum` class adds instance methods for the various options in your `enum`.

This normally works fine, but if you have multiple `enum`'s with the same value inside, the model simply won't be able to handle the different instance methods, hence your error.

Comment: Thanks :) This is working in Rails 5...Any solution for Rails 4?

Comment: It should work in Rails 4, at least according to the docs. How are you able to switch your app between the two so easily?

Comment: tried but it gives an error 
undefined method `each_with_index' for :relationship_status:Symbol

Comment: Can you give me the `each_with_index` code you're using?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98331/discussion-between-rich-peck-and-haseeb-ahmad).

Comment: I'm faced with the exact same problem. Any luck for rails 4?

Answer (score 4):

For Rails 4, you can backport prefix and suffix support from the current implementation. Worked for me, but use at your own risk!

Simply [copy this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rails/rails/a2eb7962d3986c787d8ca66faca57c26617be499/activerecord/lib/active_record/enum.rb) to config/initialisers/enum.rb (or anywhere else that will be processed during server boot, e.g. a lib file if you add it to your path). That's the raw source from [the Rails 5 enum implementation](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/a2eb7962d3986c787d8ca66faca57c26617be499/activerecord/lib/active_record/enum.rb).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `_prefix or _suffix` options when you need to define multiple enums with same values. If the passed value is true, the methods are `prefixed/suffixed` with the name of the enum.

```
  enum gender: [:Male, :Female,:All], _prefix: :gender
  enum qualification: [:Uneducated,:Matric, :Inter, :Graduation, :Masters, :PHD,:All], _suffix: true
```

Now you can access `user.gender_Male!` and `user.Matric_qualification!`

or

`user.gender_Male?` and `user.Matric_qualification?`

Comment: Thanks :) This is working in Rails 5...Any solution for Rails 4?